# I have an error message in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

> Error (10409): VHDL Type Conversion error at execute.vhd(91): converted type of object near text or symbol "SIGNED" must match bit_vector type of target object

The relevant code line is:

```
WHEN "101"  =>  ALU_output_mux  <= std_logic_vector(signed(Binput) sra to_integer(unsigned(Sign_extend (10 downto 6))));
```

I don't understand the reason for that error.

Thanks

Comment: All we can do is say that either the arguments to "Signed" or the result you are assigning it to are the wrong type. Without any relevant type declarations, anything more would be guesswork.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As Brian Drummond says, there could be various reasons why you're getting this error.